# How can I enable X11 forwarding to a Debian server box?

Tags: ssh, debian, x11, x11forwarding

I want to connect to a server with SSH (a Debian installation in a VMware image). On that server I want to call `gitk` a repository viewer for `git`. What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To enable X11 forwarding on the server you need at least the `xauth` program.

1. Install `xbase-clients` on the server (or the package that contains `xauth`)
2. Connect to the server with SSH using the following command

   `ssh -X servername`
3. Run the program

Comment: On Debian 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 there is an 'xauth' package which seems to be the only requirement to make X11 forwarding work (you have to disconnect and reconnect to the ssh session after installing it)

Answer (score 7):

Also, check that `X11Forwarding` is set to yes in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (it is apparently the default in Debian).

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to Peter's correct answer:

If you're using Windows, you can install [Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/) to display remote X applications running locally, it's more transparent than remote desktop.

If you just want to execute a shell command remotely, it's "ssh user@hostname command". For even more info, see the man page for the [ssh command](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1), or see all the [OpenSSH man pages](http://www.openssh.org/manual.html). If you haven't yet used [scp](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=scp&sektion=1) or [ssh-agent](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-agent&sektion=1), they will make your life easier.